# Error message for my use of the format() built-in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

Here's my code, and the error message:

```
>>> message = ‘The price of this {0:s} laptop I {1:d} USD and the exchange rate is {2:4.2f} USD to 1 EUR’.format(‘Apple’, 1299, 1.23342342)
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

According to the book I'm following, my code is correct. I should mention that the word "The" is highlighted in pink and the words "and" "is" both show up yellow.

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong quotes. Use the `'` or `"` characters to quote your string.

Comment: Thanks, yep, you're right!

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong quote characters, you need to use `'` or `"`.

```
message = 'The price of this {0:s} laptop I {1:d} USD and the exchange rate is {2:4.2f} USD to 1 EUR'.format('Apple', 1299, 1.23342342)
```

Comment: Of course, thanks. I sure wish the  error message would point at the quotes.